# QThread moveToThread. Synchronization in QThread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qsignalmapper

I want to write some class which has to work in own thread. 
I've read this article: `http://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects`. It advises to move object which has to work in own thread, like:

```
TestClass tst;
QThread *thread = new QThread();
tst.moveToThread(thread);
thread->start();
QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), &tst, SLOT(start()));
```

And in `slot` of TestClass I put all initializations procedures.
1. Can I moveToThread in TestClass' constructor? Like:

```
TestClass::TestClass() {
  QThread *thread = new QThread();
  this->moveToThread(thread);
  thread->start();  
  QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(start()));
}
```

After that all objects of this class will be working in own threads.

2. In `TestClass` I have private `struct` which can be changed in both threads.
   Should I use `mutex` for that or use signal/slots:

   ```
   void TestClass::changeStruct(int newValue) {
     // invoked in main thread

     emit this->changeValue(newValue);

   }

   // slot
   void TestClass::changeStructSlot(int newValue) {
     // this slot will be invoked in the second thread
     this._struct.val = newValue;
   }
   ```

Comment: Why have a function that just emits a signal, why not connect a signal to `TestClass::changeStructSlot` and emit that signal where you call `TestClass::changeStruct`, or call [`QMetaMethod::invoke`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetamethod.html#invoke) / [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod).

Comment: Better connect `SIGNAL(start())` before starting the thread, or you risk missing the signal by a race condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I wouldn't do it at least from the design point of view. On top of what `TestClass` is supposed to do you try to add internal thread management. Also `TestClass` destructor is going to be little bit complicated because of thread management.
2. Every `TestClass` object has its own `struct`. If the call from main thread is the only way to change `val` then nothing has to be done. If the `val` can be changed from more than 1 thread including its own then use `QMutex`.

Comment: 2. So if I will use slots/signals how I've written above that means that method can be invoked in an any threads but `slot` (`changeStructSlot`) always will be executed in thread of TestClass, isn't?

Comment: Correct. And it should be no concurrency unless you decide do not use default connection type. This page explains details: [Signals and Slots Across Threads](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads)

Comment: Then I think it will be more easy way. Will not use `mutex`. `TestClass::TestClass() 
{
  /* default type connection - Auto Connection. */
  connect(this, SIGNAL(changeValue(int)), this, SLOT(changeStructSlot(int)));
  
  /* other stuff */
}

void TestClass::changeStruct(int newValue) {
  /* this method can be invoked in an any thread */
  emit this->changeValue(newValue);
}` right?

Comment: Yes, this or direct call `emit TestClassObject->changeValue(newValue);` should work and no need for mutex because of Auto Connection.